# Url-based web site publishing on Windows Server platform

Tags: windows-server-2003, web-hosting, microsoft-ftmg-2010

I have a Windows 2008 Enterprise SP2 server in a datacenter. It is 32bit OS. I need to be able to do a "smart" url-based web site publishing. So that with a single external IP I can publish many sites on port 80, and some firewall logic resolves, based on a requested URL, which site in IIS gets the request.

Forefront TMG 2010 has this feature, but it is not supported on 32bit systems. Is there a software solution that can satissfy my need on Windows 2K8 platform? Thank you.

P.S. Perhaps there is a workaround or a tweak to do what I need in IIS?

Comment: Are the websites hosted one IIS server or are there multiples?

Comment: IIS in the same network. If it will work, IIS can be on this very same "front-facing" server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you just need to use Host Headers on your IIS server. These work kind of like Virtual Hosts in Apache - there's no requirement for anything* inbetween the server and the internet unless you want to expand to multiple IIS servers.

Here is an IIS7 how to page which will get you started:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx

*You still need a firewall, etc, but it doesn't have to do anything for this to work